# NullPointerException when using Scanner.nextInt()

Tags: java

I am creating a program that calculates how many numbers between A and B are divisible by K. This program should allow the user to input first the number of test cases then get the corresponding A, B, and K values depending on the number of test cases.
Sample Input:

```
    2
    1
    10
    3
    8
    20
    4
```

Output would be:

```
    Case 1: 3
    Case 2: 4
```

However, I  keep getting a NullPointerException right after hitting enter after the second line. In this case, I only get to enter:

```
     2
     1
```

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ABK {

public static void cases(int no, int[] first, int[] second, int[] div){
    int[] outputs = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < no; i++){
        for(int x = first[i]; x <= second[i]; x++){
            if(x%(div[i]) == 0)
                outputs[i]++;
            else continue;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < no; i++){
        System.out.println("Case " + (i+1) + ": " + outputs[i]);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int noOfCases = 0;
    int[] a = null, b = null, k = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    noOfCases = scanner.nextInt();
    if(noOfCases < 0 || noOfCases > 1000){
        System.out.println("Invalid number of cases. Only numbers from 1 to 100 are allowed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfCases; i++){
        a[i] = scanner.nextInt(); //THIS IS WHERE THE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION APPEARS
        b[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        k[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfCases; i++){
        if(a[i] < 1 || a[i] > 1000){
            System.out.println("Invalid value of a. Only numbers from 1 to 1000 are allowed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(b[i] < 1 || b[i] > 1000){
            System.out.println("Invalid value of b. Only numbers from 1 to 1000 are allowed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(a[i] > b[i]){
            System.out.println("Invalid value of b. It must be larger than a.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(k[i] < 1 || k[i] > 1000){
            System.out.println("Invalid value of k. Only numbers from 1 to 9999 are allowed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    cases(noOfCases, a, b, k);
}
```

}

I've tried other "fixes" such as initializing the Scanner variable or using a new class that implements scanner.nextInt() but none worked for me.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger, examine variables, etc?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm aware of what a NullPointerException is. I just don't understand why it was happening in my program and I couldn't find the answer in the thread you're claiming is similar to what I asked. Thanks for the reference anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never instantiate `a` array. Therefore, you get an NPE when trying to access it.

The same exception will happen for `b` and `k`.

You can instantiate the arrays that way

```
a = new int[noOfCases];
```

Comment: You're right! I thought this line `int[] a = null, b = null, k = null` was enough. I tried instantiating them one by one, using noOfCases as size and it worked! I get the difference now. Thank you for your answer. I'll keep this in mind.